# Importing variables to new class in Java

Tags: java, class, object

I was working on a program that replicates the german drinking game "Mäxchen", however, I cannot figure out how to import one of the variables to a new class. I am using eclipse, jdk18, and windows 10.
Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.*;

public class MäxchenDiceRoll {

    public void rollDice() {

//beginning of user input for amount of players
        Scanner playerAmountInput = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter amount of players \n");

            String playerAmount = playerAmountInput.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Amount of players are: " + playerAmount);
                //end of user input for amount of players
Random ran = new Random();
            
        int die1;
        int die2;
        
        die1 = ran.nextInt(6)+1;
        die2 = ran.nextInt(6)+1;
        
    int result;
        
if(die1>die2) {
    result = (die1*10) + die2;
    System.out.println("The result is: " + result);
} else if(die2>die1) {
    result = (die2*10) + die1;
    //System.out.println("The result is: " + result);
} else if(die1==die2) {
    result = (die1*10) + die2;
    System.out.println("The result is: " + result);
    
} 

    }

}
```

I want to port the result variable to a different class, but I am at a loss as to how to approach this. Any help would be appreciated, many thanks.

Comment: You can change the return type of the method to int instead of void and return whichever variable of the correct type you want. Then in the other class create an instance of the first one and call your method.

Comment: You mean you want only the answer on a different class? means you wanna show your `rollDice()` method into another class? 

if yes, then declare it as static and easily you can call it from another class

Comment: When I change the type from void to int and add "return result;" it says that it has not been initialised, even though I stated earlier in the code "int result;"

Comment: @PythonSux `int result` does not initialize anything. The variable you return needs to have a value for all possible execution paths of your code. It needs to have a value in each branch of your if/else if/else if and another one in case it never hits any of those branches. I recommend that you read a tutorial on the very basics of Java, because this is very basic stuff that you should know before you can write any kind of moderately complex code: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/